# Using AJAX to populate image list in static JS file

Tags: javascript, php, tinymce, tinymce-4

I have started using TinyMCE, which allows users to create custom plugins.

I am working on a custom plugin to replace the out-of-the-box emoticons plugin.

The code that powers a plugin is defined in the "**plugin.min.js**" file inside the relevant plugin directory - e.g.

```
/assets/includes/tinymce/plugins/emoticons1_faces/
```

This is a sample file:

```
tinymce.PluginManager.add("emoticons9", function(a, b) {
    function c() {
        var a;
        return a = '<table role="list" class="mce-grid">', tinymce.each(d, function(c) {
            a += "<tr>", tinymce.each(c, function(c) {
                var d = b + "/img/" + c + ".svg";
                a += '<td><a href="#" data-mce-url="' + d + '" data-mce-alt="' + c + '" tabindex="-1" role="option" aria-label="' + c + '"><img src="' + d + '" style="width: 18px; height: 18px" role="presentation" /></a></td>'
            }), a += "</tr>"
        }), a += "</table>"
    }
    var d = [
        ["09_001","09_002","09_003"]
    ];
    a.addButton("emoticons9", {
        type: "panelbutton",
        panel: {
            role: "application",
            autohide: !0,
            html: c,
            onclick: function(b) {
                var c = a.dom.getParent(b.target, "a");
                c && (a.insertContent('<img src="' + c.getAttribute("data-mce-url") + '" width="18" height="18" alt="' + c.getAttribute("data-mce-alt") + '" />'), this.hide())
            }
        },
        tooltip: "Emoticons - Diversity"
    })
});
```

If I want to change the images that the plugin uses, I have to change the file references in this line:

```
["09_001","09_002","09_003"]
```

I can't simply replace "plugin.min.js" with a php page which uses echo to output the javascript code sot that I can dynamically generate the list of images to use (e.g. so I could have a "favourites" or "recently used" option).

I asked for advice on the TinyMCE forum about this, and was told:

> TinyMCE runs 100% client side so you cannot create PHP plugins ... you
>   could use AJAX calls to grab data from your application and then
>   replace the contents of that array with your application's data.

I've used AJAX and PHP before, but I'm not sure how I'd go about implementing this advice.

For example, say I wanted to populate the list of images using image names from a database, I wondered if I could ask for advice about how to start?

I don't have a problem with the process of generating the list of images using PHP, I just can't see how I'd get the static "plugin.min.js" file to be able to be populated with the output of that PHP script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin currently has a list hardcoded:

```
var d = [
    ["09_001","09_002","09_003"]
];
```

You would instead use an AJAX call to fetch an array of values - this is JavaScript in the plugin file.

That AJAX code would call a PHP page you create and it would return an array of the values you want to use.  It would be very easy to have your PHP return a JSON array to the JavaScript code.

You then use that array instead of the hard coded array that is currently used.

**UPDATE:** The unminified version of the plugin uses the following variable to manage the list of valid emoticons (note that it is an array of arrays of strings):

```
var emoticons = [
    ["cool", "cry", "embarassed", "foot-in-mouth"],
    ["frown", "innocent", "kiss", "laughing"],
    ["money-mouth", "sealed", "smile", "surprised"],
    ["tongue-out", "undecided", "wink", "yell"]
];
```

...so you just need to have your AJAX call update the value of that variable:

```
tinymce.util.XHR.send({
    url: 'yourserverurlhere.php',
    success: function(returnedData) {
        //process the returnedData into a JavaScript ARRAY of ARRAYS 
        emoticons = [
            ["cool", "cry"]  // this is hardcoded but you get the idea
        ];
    }
});
```

note you do NOT use var when referencing `emoticons` in the success handler otherwise you are making a new local variable that hides the plugins's `emoticons` variable.

As this is a asynchronous call the "default" emoticons will be available until the call returns your new values.